# select query error fired in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i am getting this error **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NIRAV' in 'where clause'** when i am trying to execute following code.

```
package all_forms;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Select_operation {

private Connection con=null;
private PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
private ResultSet rs=null;
String query;
public Select_operation(Connection conn)
{
    con=conn;
}
public ResultSet select(String search)
{
    query="select * from student where id="+search+" or name like'"+search+"%'";
    try
    {
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+e, "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return rs;
}
```

}

Comment: 1) You're using ticks (') around like and not backticks (`) correct? 2) what is the value of search being passed in?  Based on your name for this site and the value it's looking at, I'm guessing your searching on your name and the system is interpreting it as a column name instead of a search string.  you really should consider using parameterized queries as it will reduce SQL injection and reduce the occurrence of this type of error.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `search`?

Comment: @EdGibbs in search i will either pass id or name.

Comment: Got it. JW already figured that out; your query with `search = 'NIRAV'` would translate to `... WHERE id=NIRAV or name like'NIRAV%'`, treating the `id=NIRAV` as comparing columns. Also take JW's advice on the prepared statements - it will lengthen your career :)

Comment: @EdGibbs thanks i am learning these all these coding and i really like it thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the value of the `ID` should be wrap with a string because you are supplying a non numeric value of it.

```
query="select * from student where id='"+search+"' or name like '"+search+"%'";
                                      ^ HERE     ^
```

you should consider using `PreparedStatement` to avoid `SQL Injection`.

```
// con is your active connection

String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = ? OR name LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
prest.setString(1, search);
prest.setString(2, search + "%");
ResultSet _set = prest.executeQuery();
```

you should also add this line on top of the class

```
import java.sql.*;
```

*PreparedStatements avoid your code from sql injection.*

**[more on this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)**